# Custom stopword analyzer is not woring properly

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, analyzer, stop-words

I have created an index with a custom analyzer for stop words. I want that elastic-search to ignore these words at the time of searching. Then I added one document data in elasticsearch mapping. 
but when I am querying in kibana for "the" keyword with the query. It should not show any successful match, because in my_analzer I have put "the" in my_stop_word section. But it is showing the match. I have studied that if you mention one analyzer at the time of indexing in the mapping field. then it takes that analyzer by default at the time of the query. 
please help!

```
PUT /pandey
{ 
  "settings":  
  { 
    "analysis":  
    { 
      "analyzer":  
      { 
        "my_analyzer":  
        { 
          "tokenizer": "standard", 
          "filter": [ 
            "my_stemmer", 
            "english_stop", 
            "my_stop_word", 
            "lowercase" 
          ] 
        } 
      }, 
      "filter": { 
        "my_stemmer": { 
          "type": "stemmer", 
          "name": "english" 
        }, 
        "english_stop":{ 
          "type": "stop", 
          "stopwords": "_english_" 
        }, 
        "my_stop_word": { 
          "type": "stop", 
          "stopwords": ["robot", "love", "affection", "play", "the"] 
        } 
      }
    } 
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "dialog": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}


 PUT pandey/_doc/1
 {
    "dailog" : "the boy is a robot. he is in love. i play cricket"
 }

 GET pandey/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "dailog": "the"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This works in 7.6 version. Could you try to use and see what tokens are getting generated using [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html). Also just cross check using `GET pandey/_mapping` to see if the mapping is as expected. Many times people use templates for language filters and all and they see unexpected results. Also just try deleting the index and re-creating it to see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small spelling mistake can lead to this.

You defined mapping for `dialog` but added document with field name `dailog`. the dynamic field mappings behavior of elastic will index it without error. we can disable it though.

So the query, `"dailog": "the"` will get the result using default analyzer.